# Describing the sound of liquid hitting the floor

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

I'm searching for a word describing the sound of liquid hitting the floor, nothing like water — more like milkshake/vomit.

I know this sounds strange, but I was thinking of *plunge*. Only to discover that it's more in use for people diving into water...

Comment: Milkshakes won't make much noise. They are aerated, and the speed of sound in a aerated fluid is so small it just can't make collimated waves over a surface and transfer that to the air. Plus it's really viscous, so it doesn't want to reverberate either. So it's really a matter of the floor. [Last table](http://www.drphysics.com/teacup/teacup.html) Sorry, just came from Engineering.se . There is an *acoustics* tag over there if you are interested.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This comes to my mind:

> **splat** 2 informal
>   *noun*
>   a sound of something soft and wet or heavy striking a surface : *the goblin makes a huge splat as he hits the ground*.

Could apply to a quantity of water, I imagine. Also, it's a 19th century abbreviation of **splatter**, which might also work.

Comment: I would say 'splat' is used for something with more substance. 'Wet', yes but not a liquid. A custard pie, for example, might 'splat'.

Comment: well, milkshake & vomit are more substancy

Answer (score 7):

"Splosh" was my first thought. It's just a variation of "splash," but I always think of splashing in a bathtub. "Slosh" would be the sound you get shaking liquid in a basin of some sort. Thus, I offer "splosh."

...Now that I think about it, though, a lot of the time when something as thick as a milkshake hits the ground it makes more of a "slap" than anything else...

May I suggest an experiment...?

Comment: I like the idea of experimenting. The great thing with onomatopoeia is that if you were to make up a word entirely, it shouldn't matter too much as people will mostly get the idea - as long as you replicate the sound accurately enough. So yes, try it out and see how you think it sounds!

Comment: Yes but if you try to describe a scene and the first sentence is "you hear a sound of squaalaaash in the room".. It could get quite confusing.

Comment: ...A little silly, perhaps, but I wouldn't say confusing, and silly only because of the a's. I wouldn't think anything unusual of "You hear a squalash in the room."

Answer (score 2):

What about **plop**? It has a thick sound to it. According to Wikitionary, it's even been converted to a noun in the UK, as a slang term for excrement, presumably from the sound of its hitting the water and its having just the right consistency.

Comment: @gbutters You are aware that _excrement_ is another word for your solid, correct?

Comment: @gbutters No, it isn't.  Yogurt, a colloid -- an even mixture of solid and liquid, hence "thick" -- can _plop_ just fine.  And besides, is _vomit_ not solid?

Comment: Errm...Not to intrude on this lovely discussion, but, FWIW, I'd say onomatopoeia have pretty nebulous definitions. If I say someone's milkshake/vomit plopped onto the floor, well then plop it did! At the end of the day, this is going to come down to personal preference and perception... What I say makes a raspy sound may well sound a whispery one to the person next to me, and these liquid words are little different, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

> splash, plop, or drip"

come to mind (depending on velocity)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest **splop**:  halfway between a splosh (which sounds rather wet) and a plop (which sounds rather thick and viscous).

Answer (score 0):

All of the words given are examples of onomatopoeia - words that describe exactly the sound they refer to (like 'bang' and 'clap').

Some good onomatopoeic words for liquid are:

drip, drop, plop - these would describe single droplets of liquid hitting the floor individually, as from a loose faucet/tap.

drum, pit-a-pat, patter - like the droplets above but when many come down at once, like with rain.

sploosh, splosh, splash - these would describe larger quantities of liquid, like spilling a drink.

Hope this helps. I'm sure there are more, too.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a **swash**. But this inconsequential answer didn't have thirty characters, so here is some bogus text to please the silly computer.

Comment: ...When that happens to me, I just put in another ellipsis!...I am rather fond of them...

Comment: @kitukwyer: Ah! But then... yes, it works, by Jove!